# memory alignment with mkl_malloc

Tags: c, intel-mkl

This question might just show that I haven't understand something important in C:

The Intel Math Kernel library provides a way to set the memory alignment when allocating memory. On the other hand I pass arrays to mkl lapack routines just by reference. So how does the lapack routine know about the alignment of the array? It has to, since the memory alignment determines at which memory address is a particular array value, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The routine does not need to know about alignment. Alignment only determines the starting address of the array (which coincides with the address of the first element), the address of the rest of the elements is determined by the starting address and element size.

Comment: so that's from wikipedia: "Data alignment means putting the data at a memory offset equal to some multiple of the word size, which increases the system's performance due to the way the CPU handles memory. To align the data, it may be necessary to insert some meaningless bytes between the end of the last data structure and the start of the next, which is data structure padding." That somehow implies to me that the address of the second array entry will be determined by data alignment chosen.

Comment: No, the address of the 2nd entry is determined by the element size, which in turn, is determined by alignment requested for that particular element type. But that alignment is a property of the element type, which is different from the alignment used by mkl_malloc. PS: drop wikipedia and get a decent book. Wikipedia is kinda OK if you already know the stuff, but is awful for learning from scratch.

Comment: And the part of "increasing performance" should be taken with a grain of salt. It is true only up to a certain limit, since larger alignment = more wasted space = more L1 cache misses = decreased performance. As I said: forget wikipedia.

Comment: @zvrba: Have to disagree on this last point. Proper alignment with `BLAS` libraries can be **extremely** important for performance reasons. If unaligned data is used, the library may not be able to use `SSE, SSE2 etc` instruction sets (because they require `128 bit` alignment) and this *can* result in serious performance impacts. There should be a whole section in the `MKL` documentation that covers this...

Comment: I was writing about alignment in general. For example, it would be VERY wasteful to align a struct containing, f.ex., only a double and an int (total size 12) to more than 16 bytes.  Already here, 4 bytes = 25% of space is wasted, which can be significant if you're handling large arrays. But yes, you too are right, proper alignment tends to be important for SSE memory operations. (Though, the latest CPUs have significantly lower, if any, overhead when loading unaligned data into sse registers.)